# How to remove dynamically a row of table using BaseAdapter when a column is empty?

Tags: java, android, baseadapter, layout-inflater

my question is above. My code is below.
As you can see, some of the data is empty e.g. "20:11", "", "11:25" ...
I would like that the row from layout inflate has been immediately removed when a field is empty or if there is a better solution has dynamically created when a field is non empty.

```
public class Zlecenia extends Activity {

    ListView listview;

    ArrayList<ListData> myList = new ArrayList<>();

    String[] strefa = new String[]{
            "Jerozolimskie 20/22", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4",
            "Title 5", "Title 6", "Title 7", "Title 8"
    };
    String[] adres = new String[]{
            "Desc 1", "Desc 2", "Desc 3", "Desc 4",
            "Desc 5", "Desc 6", "Desc 7", "Desc 8"
    };
    String[] data = new String[]{
            "20:11", "", "11:25", "", "15:11", "11:25", "15:11", "11:25"
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.zlecenia);

        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        for (int i = 0; i < strefa.length; i++) {
            ListData ld = new ListData();
            ld.setStrefa(strefa[i]);
            ld.setAdres(adres[i]);
            ld.setData(data[i]);
            myList.add(ld);
        }

        listview.setAdapter(new MyBaseAdapter(this, myList));

    }

}
```

And BaseAdapter:

```
public class MyBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

// Other methods of extends BaseAdapter
...

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        MyViewHolder mViewHolder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.zlecenia_lista, parent, false);
            mViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);
        } else {
            mViewHolder = (MyViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        ListData currentListData = getItem(position);

        mViewHolder.strefa.setText(currentListData.getStrefa());
        mViewHolder.adres.setText(currentListData.getAdres());
        mViewHolder.data.setText(currentListData.getData());

        return convertView;
    }

    private class MyViewHolder {
        TextView strefa, adres, data;

        public MyViewHolder(View item) {
            strefa = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.strefa);
            adres = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.adres);
            data = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.data);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: you can check id any field is empty at the time of adding in list .if it is empty don't add it.than it will not reflect  in your list view

Comment: I have marked on red findViewById in MyBaseAdapter class, so I can't find any ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so you want all the row (item) of a list to be removed (hide) if data equal ""

here what i propose :

```
public class MyBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

// Other methods of extends BaseAdapter
...

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        MyViewHolder mViewHolder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.zlecenia_lista, parent, false);
            mViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);
        } else {
            mViewHolder = (MyViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        ListData currentListData = getItem(position);

        mViewHolder.strefa.setText(currentListData.getStrefa());
        mViewHolder.adres.setText(currentListData.getAdres());
        mViewHolder.data.setText(currentListData.getData());
        // try this
        if(currentListData.getData().equals("")) {
              convertView.setVisibility(View.GONE) // all the row is hided
        }else {
              convertView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) // display the row
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    private class MyViewHolder {
        TextView strefa, adres, data;

        public MyViewHolder(View item) {
            strefa = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.strefa);
            adres = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.adres);
            data = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.data);
        }
    }

}
```

hope that was helpful, if any trouble leave a comment !

good luck !

Comment: Each item is a table. I want hide only one row in item, not that item. My table has three rows and two column. I want hide this row, when a string is empty.

Comment: I did it! Instead convertView.setVisibility(View.GONE) I put convertView.findViewById(R.id.rowdata).setVisibility(View.GONE); Thanks!

Comment: I didn't know that you have three row inside your item yes the findviewbyId() would work, please don't forget to put the answer as resolved, good luck !

Comment: Yes, I have three rows in an element. I noticed that my last item has hidden row but a data is non empty. Why? When I removed this condition: if (convertView == null) { ... then is well. If this condition is required?

Comment: if removing the condition worked for you then you can just removed, the condition is just to optimize, for each row was inflated and not destroyed yet it will be used again, if your item (row) don't contains so much views and you don't have so much row in your list, you will not notice any change